# Activating a Python virtual environment and calling python script inside another python script

Tags: python, ubuntu, pipenv, virtual-environment

I am using pipenv for managing my packages. I want to write a python script that calls another python script that uses a different Virtual Environment(VE).

How can I run python script 1 that uses VE1 and call another python script (script2 that uses VE2).

I found this code for the cases where there is no need for changing the virtual environment.

```
import os
os.system("python myOtherScript.py arg1 arg2 arg3")
```

The only idea that I had was simply navigating to the target project and activate shell:

```
os.system("cd /home/mmoradi2/pgrastertime/")
os.system("pipenv  shell")
os.system("python test.py")
```

but it says:

> Shell for /home/..........-GdKCBK2j already activated.
>     No action taken to avoid nested environments.

What should I do now?
in fact my own code needs VE1 and the subprocess (second script) needs VE2. How can I call the second script inside my code?

In addition, the second script is used as a command line tool that accepts the inputs with flags:

```
python3 pgrastertime.py -s ./sql/postprocess.sql -t brasdor_c_07_0150  
-p xml -f  -r ../data/brasdor_c_07_0150.object.xml
```

How can I call it using the solution of @tzaman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each virtualenv has its own `python` executable which you can use directly to execute the script.

Using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) (more versatile than `os.system`):

```
import subprocess

venv_python = '/path/to/other/venv/bin/python'
args = [venv_python, 'my_script.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
subprocess.run(args)
```

Comment: `subprocess` is in the standard library, you don't need to install anything. If you're on Python 2, `run` doesn't exist since it was added in 3.5+ but you can use `subprocess.call` instead; read the linked documentation for the "Older high level API".

Comment: actually my second srcipt that I want to call accepts flags:
pgrastertime.py -s ./sql/postprocess.sql -t brasdor_c_20190507_0150  -p xml -f  

how can I import the flags using your code?

Comment: @milad just add all the flags to the `args` list in order.

Comment: I had an error.
Permission denied:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/mmoradi2/.local/share/virtualenvs/pgrastertime-d4CrnaVY/bin/activate'